# Sqlite persistently executes sql even when conditions are not met

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask

Why does this code still add users to sqlite3 db even though `len(cursor.fetchall())` is greater than 0?

```
#just for refrence, the issue is in the next block of code
def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    return db

@app.route("/add_user", methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    cursor = get_db().cursor()
    response = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", (data['email'],))
    print('res_length', len(response.fetchall()))
    res_length = len(response.fetchall())

    if res_length > 0:
        return jsonify({"message": "User exists"})
    else: #This always executes!!! Why?????
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (data['name'], data['email'], data['password']))
        get_db().commit()
        get_db().close()
        return jsonify({
        "message": "New User added",
        "status": "ok",
        "status_code": 200
        })
```

Using Flask-1.0.3 and Python-3.7.3

Comment: @shaik moeed the question is why doesnt the if/else work? Why does the sql in else block execute everytime?

Comment: Then your question itself is an answer. `Why does the sql in else block execute everytime?`  Cuz `response.fetchall` is `None`. Have you tried after replacing with `%s`?

Comment: @shaik moeed. Yes I have. And I was getting a sqlite3.OperationalError: syntax error.

Comment: @shaikmoeed I think I have found the issue. In the print statement `print('res_length', len(response.fetchall()))` there was a call to `response.fetchall()`. So the next time I am calling `response.fetchall()` in the next line I get an empty list. I don't know why this is, but removing the print statement solves the issue. Also apparently '%s' throws a syntax error in Python flavour of sqlite3. Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can only call `.fetchall()` once on a cursor response. Further attempts to call `.fetchall()` on the same cursor response will return an empty list. 
Removing the print statement: `print('res_length', len(response.fetchall()))` allowed me to use `res_length = len(response.fetchall())` and solved the issue.